# Constant pixel size in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to add some extra padding to the right side of a scrollbar, but when I zoom in the browser window (with ctrl+= and ctrl+-) the actual pixel width of the padding grows and shrinks accordingly (as if I had specified it in ems). I would like the `right` property for the container to be exactly 8 pixels, not 0.5ems (8/16=0.5).

Is there a way to set the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` css properties to a fixed value that doesn't change depending on the font size (I don't mind using JavaScript if I have to)?

Here's my CSS:

```
#page-bg
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 2em; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}

#page-content
{
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px; /* these are what I'm talking about */
    left: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: can you add the CSS to the question?

Comment: Zooming works differently in different browsers. Some zoom only the font size (to which the layout then can adapt), some simply zoom the whole layout (including images), such that the effective screen size shrinks. (And some don't support zooming at all.)

Comment: @m4tt1mus : I added the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the "padding width" fixed even when you zoom, you need to find out the zoom level using JavaScript.

It's sort of possible, but it's totally not worth it because it's unreliable, see: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Maybe there's a better way to achieve the same thing - you should post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo of what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers appear to virtually change the resolution of the page; this change is out of the control of javascript and css. The short answer is you can't and if you find one browser that does work you have to decide between standards and consistency and how it looks on one browser. Html, css and javascript arnt made for this type of control